# Run a .ahk on stratup

Tags: windows-8, boot, autohotkey

In Windows 7, I used to copy .ahk files to start-up folder to make them to start automatically. But this does not work in Windows 8. Is there any solution?

Comment: If copying into this location(“C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup”) doesn't work.. You can use Task scheduler to run .ahk files at startup

Comment: What do you mean when you say "this does not work"? Is it just that you're unable to find that folder? It is tricky under Windows 8; but if you open a File Explorer and paste in the path that ISAAC gave in his comment, that should get you there.

Comment: @echristopherson It's on the path but is not run by Windows.

Comment: Strange. Works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I found the source of the problem. An old version of AHT had installed beside the newer version. Unsintalling the old one, resolved the issue.

Thanks all for comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Compile `copy .ahk` to `.exe` file using "Convert .ahk to .exe" tool that is in Autohotkey distribution. I think in that case it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems everything in the startup folder needs to be a shortcut (.lnk). Everything in the statup folder on my Windows 8 partition is a shortcut including the AutoHotkey script and other things I placed there manually, and I seem to recall this solving the same problem for me after much frustration.

To make a shortcut in Windows, click and drag the file from another location and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> when releasing the mouse button.